# TextBox validating, integer with symbol

Tags: c#, regex, validation, textbox

I want to limit the user only able to key in integer (not double) and with symbol `","` in the textBox. I have try this code, but it always pop on the messagebox when i try to erase the wrong input.

```
if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox4.Text, @"^[0-9,-Key.Back]"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only alphabetical characters");
    //textBox4.Text.Remove(textBox4.Text.Length - 1);
    //textBox4.Clear();
}
```

Please help.

Comment: You cannot use `Key.Back` in the regex pattern. Process this key in the KeyDown/KeyPress event handler (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288939/how-can-i-determine-if-the-backspace-has-been-pressed-in-the-keypress-event)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are running the code in the `TextChanged` event handler. The problem is with your regex. You say you need to allow digits and commas, but you are checking if there are digits, `,`, some range between `,` and `K` and some letters (`e`, `y`, etc) with a literal dot *at the beginning of the string*.

I think you want to fix it like

```
if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^[0-9,]*$"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers and commas.");
}
```

The [`^[0-9,]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/nW0sL4/1) regex returns true when the whole input contains digits and commas from start to end.

If you need to allow just whole numbers with `,` as a decimal separator, use

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)?$
```

If you want to allow whole integer numbers with `,` as a digit grouping (thousand separator) symbol, use

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$
```

To process the `Key.Back` key you need to implement the behavior you want in the KeyDown/KeyPress event handler, see [*How can I determine if the Backspace has been pressed in the KeyPress event?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288939/how-can-i-determine-if-the-backspace-has-been-pressed-in-the-keypress-event).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != ',' && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Digits, commas and backspace only");
    }
}
```